# CdkDragDrop | Angular and Firebase Firestore | Google Developers Tutorial incorrect?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I've been working on the Angular - Firebase tutorial from Google (https://developers.google.com/codelabs/building-a-web-app-with-angular-and-firebase) for several days, but I've encountered a persistent issue that I can't seem to resolve. Despite starting the tutorial from scratch three times to ensure I haven't missed any steps, the problem persists.

The main issue arises when I attempt to use the CdkDragDrop event in my app.component.html file. It consistently throws an error that reads:

> Argument of type 'CdkDragDrop<Task[] | null, any, any>' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'CdkDragDrop<Task[], Task[],
> any>'.ngtsc(2345)

> app.component.ts(20, 7): Error occurs in the
> template of component AppComponent.

The error is displayed for `drop($event)` in the following code snippet of `app.component.html`:

```
  <mat-card
      cdkDropList
      id="inProgress"
      #inProgressList="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="inProgress | async"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList, doneList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
      class="list">
      <p class="empty-label" *ngIf="(inProgress | async)?.length === 0">Empty list</p>
      <app-task (edit)="editTask('inProgress', $event)" *ngFor="let task of inProgress | async" cdkDrag [task]="task"></app-task>
    </mat-card>
```

The `drop` method in `app.component.ts` looks like this:

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Task[]>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      return;
    }
    const item = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
    this.store.firestore.runTransaction(() => {
      const promise = Promise.all([
        this.store.collection(event.previousContainer.id).doc(item.id).delete(),
        this.store.collection(event.container.id).add(item),
      ]);
      return promise;
    });
    transferArrayItem(
      event.previousContainer.data,
      event.container.data,
      event.previousIndex,
      event.currentIndex
    );
  }
```

This error has left me stuck and unable to progress further in the tutorial. I was able to successfully complete the tutorial each time up to this point, but from here on, nothing progresses because this error is displayed, and I simply can't find the source. I've spent a significant amount of time researching and troubleshooting, but I haven't been able to identify the root cause of the problem.

If anyone could provide assistance or guidance to help me resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:

I have updated the method as per the recommendations in the comments. I am no longer encountering errors within my project. However, during the compilation process, I'm encountering an error message that indicates a type mismatch between the data types used in my project and the data types of the collections in my Firestore database. I don't understand how that can be. If you follow the tutorial correctly (which I most certainly did), then only string attributes are stored in the individual "Task" objects and I used all three collections as specified in the tutorial and stored them the same way in my Firestore. I don't understand how then a type mismatch can be present.

Below is the updated 'drop' method:

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Task[] | null>): void {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      return;
    }
    const item = event.previousContainer?.data?.[event.previousIndex];
    if (!item) {
      return;
    }
    this.store.firestore.runTransaction(() => {
      const promise = Promise.all([
        this.store.collection(event.previousContainer!.id).doc(item.id).delete(),
        this.store.collection(event.container!.id).add(item),
      ]);
      return promise;
    });
    transferArrayItem(
      event.previousContainer!.data!,
      event.container!.data!,
      event.previousIndex,
      event.currentIndex
    );
  }
```

The error message displayed in the terminal is as follows:

```
Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentSnapshotExists<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData | undefined'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                                               ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
    13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
                                               ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:23:40
    23 export interface QueryDocumentSnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot {
                                              ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'QuerySnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>'.
  Types of property 'docs' are incompatible.
    Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>[]'.
      Type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>' is not assignable to type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.
        The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:26:32
    26 export interface QuerySnapshot<T> extends firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot {
                                      ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


Error: node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentChange<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentChange<DocumentData>'.
  The types returned by 'doc.data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:29:33
    29 export interface DocumentChange<T> extends firebase.firestore.DocumentChange {
                                       ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.


Error: node_modules/rxfire/firestore/lite/interfaces.d.ts:8:29 - error TS2314: Generic type 'AggregateQuerySnapshot<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

 8 export type CountSnapshot = lite.AggregateQuerySnapshot<{
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 9     count: lite.AggregateField<number>;
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
10 }, any, DocumentData>;
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Try `drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Task[] | null>): void`. the type comes from [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/5c822977dbe77b7db92233a877e26ae7c1bdeaad/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-events.ts#L62) and $event thinks it could be null

Comment: Ty for your tip but i tried that already and it results in a new error for  "event.previousContainer.data" that reads:`'event.previousContainer.data' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047)
(property) CdkDragDrop<Task[] | null, Task[] | null, any>.previousContainer: CdkDropList<Task[] | null>
Container from which the item was picked up. Can be the same as the container.`

Comment: I edited my post, could you please read the additional information? Maybe you have an advice?

Comment: That’s a good error to have. You just need to add null checks (just throw / return if null) and the type will narrow to Task[]. Keep type checking as strict

Comment: I set type checking back to strict and updated "drop" to handle "null" (see updated method in post). But while trying to compile there's an error displayed in the terminal indicating that there is a type mismatch between the types used in project and the types saved in firestore. But this shouldn't be possible if I strictly follow the tutorial. I just don't get it..

Comment: Where are you importing from?

Comment: Do you mean the imports in `app.component.ts` where `drop` is? If yes, the imports there are: 
`import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from './task/task';
import { CdkDragDrop, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { TaskDialogComponent, TaskDialogResult } from './task-dialog/task-dialog.component';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: I meant the firebase aspects. There's native firebase, angular firebase (compat vs new), lite version. Mixing these can cause issues which is why I asked

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, I don't really know that, as the imports were added automatically after i executed `ng add @angular/fire`. In this process I was asked what Firebase project I'd like to use and thats it. What could I do to check this?